# How to be kind when you don't like people or the world?

Tags: daily-life

I'm not sure I make a very good Buddhist. The thing is I really don't like people. They constantly disappoint me. I find most people to be so stupid. Take for example half of America and the idiotic orange leader they have elected. What kind of idiots would elect a bigoted narcissistic fool such as this?? I don't care if it's "wrong speech", I'm not going to be polite about it, the man is a delusional scumbag and such a negative force on the planet.   I cannot feel any compassion or kindness for him or his ignorant redneck believers. If someone killed him I would honestly feel glad. Yet a short distance away in Canada there is one of the most compassionate amazing leaders ever to grace the earth.  Go figure.  America seems like hell on earth to me. 
Most of the world seems to currently be controlled by dangerous mentally ill people. A lot of the time I dont even want to be here anymore. The amount of money it costs just to scrape by and survive this life now is another reason that I don't want to be here. A life that is sustained by money feels so meaningless. Sure life is more than about money but let's face it without it you die and nobody cares less. It's all so screwed up.

Comment: Some related topics might include "[How can I become less affected by politics?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/21336/254)", and "[What is the Antidote for a Hateful Temperament?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/8735/254)".

Answer (score 3):

What really matters is whether you follow the noble eightfold path and you understand the four noble truths.

Answer (score 2):

I have answered before on *metta* threads (where I usually get downvoted) but it is best to start with *equanimity* towards the world & then move up to *metta* (when appropriate). Dhammapada states:

> *171. Come! Behold this world, which is like a decorated royal chariot. Here fools flounder, but the wise have no attachment to it.*
>
> *58. Upon a heap of rubbish in the road-side ditch blooms a lotus, fragrant and pleasing.*
>
> *59. Even so, on the rubbish heap of blinded mortals the disciple of the Supremely Enlightened One shines resplendent in wisdom.*

If you are enlightened, kindness is merely a natural emotion that eminates from your own freedom of heart & kindness towards yourself in your cultivation of liberation.

Answer (score 2):

If the whole world is covered in broken glass, you could either try to wrap the world in leather or you could start wearing sandals. Trying to wrap the world in leather is like trying to change people in  the world. Wearing sandals is like fixing your own mind so the outside factors cannot bother you.

If you are overwhelmed by hate, [Metta meditation](http://www.mettainstitute.org/mettameditation.html) is the one recommended. Once you have your hate subdued to a degree you could move on to [Satipattana meditation](https://www.sirimangalo.org/text/how-to-meditate/) which will eventually eliminate anger.

Answer (score 0):

These opinions you have, what is the source of them? What is the source of any opinion? Have you met either man or did you read an article, hear a report or hear someone talking about them in a bar? If you haven't met them, consider how you have relied on intermediaries to form an opinion of two people you don't actually know. Do you trust these intermediaries (tv companies, newspapers, members of the general public)? Why? Meditate on this.

> All the world's a stage,
>   And all the men and women merely players;
>   They have their exits and their entrances,

Consider the double meaning of *entrances* and *exits*. What are the entrances and exits of a human being? What goes into the body and via what channels? What is light? What is sound? What is food and water for? What about air? How long can you go without these things? Why?

Comment: Could the person who marked this down explain why. I would genuinely like to know why this would not be a good answer to the question.